# Do I need MySQL installed on my local PC to use MySQLdb for Python to connect MySQL server remotely?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use python for manipulating some data in MySQL DB.

DB is on a remote PC. And I will use another PC with Python to connect to the DB.

When I searched how to install MySQLdb module to Python, they all said MySQL need to be installed on the local PC.

Is it right? Or I don't need to install MySQL on the local PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need it if you want to compile the Python MySQL bindings from source. If you already have the binary version of the python library then the answer is no, you don't need it.